# using static dictionary as cache may lead to leak problem?

Tags: java, arrays, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, hashmap

I have memory leak in the web application (servlet) that I am working on. I am suspicious of 1 cause and wanted to hear your ideas about it.

I use hashmaps,hashsets etc. as DB (about 20MB data loaded). These maps,sets get reloaded once in every 10 min. There are huge amount of simultaneous requests. I read that, GC passes objects, that are not collected for a time period/cycle, to a generation (old and permanent generations) which is less checked or garbage collected. I think that my usage for static maps,sets is causing me leak problem. What do you think ?

Comment: First of all thanks for the answers. I will keep your suggestions in mind.

Here are some more details;

In every ten minutes I follow these steps 
1) I create the new maps (as temporary maps) at background.
2) Clear the old maps with calling .clear() method (even assign them to null before proceeding to step 3)
3) Give reference of new maps to old maps.

May I be missing something here ?

Comment: How does the elements of your code which access these maps actually access the contents? Are you certain that no other element of the code grabs a reference to the static Map itself? Storing data application wide in a static variable is somewhat of a code smell and can lead to leak problems very simply, if not well designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a leak if you have removed all references to it.  If you're clearing out your map entirely, then it's not the source of a leak.  You should consider the fact that the JVM chooses not to GC tenured generation very often as irrelevant to you - all that matters is that you don't have a reference to it, so the JVM *could* GC it if it wants to.

There are different strategies that JVMs can use to manage GC, so I'm speaking in generalities instead of specifics here, but GCing tenured spaces tends to be very expensive and has a high impact on the application, so the JVM chooses not to do it often in general.

If you're looking at the amount of heap space used, you'll see a sawtooth pattern as items are added and eventually collected.  Don't be concerned about where the top of the sawtooth is, be concerned about where the bottom is (and how close to the maximum amount of heap space available that is).

One way to test if it really is a leak is to load test your app for a long period of time.  If you have a leak, the base amount of memory that your app is using will go up over time (the bottom of the sawtooth).  If you don't, it will remain constant.  If you do have a leak, you can use a profiler to help you find it.

Answer (score 2):

As Romain noted, the static map is a suspect. If for some reason you can't regularly clean it up explicitly, you may consider using a [WeakHashMap](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~gudmund/dprog2_2004/java/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) instead, which is

> A hashtable-based Map implementation with *weak keys*. An entry in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key is no longer in ordinary use. More precisely, the presence of a mapping for a given key will not prevent the key from being discarded by the garbage collector, that is, made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed. When a key has been discarded its entry is effectively removed from the map, so this class behaves somewhat differently than other Map  implementations.

Unfortunately, as of Java6 there seems to be no WeakHashSet in the standard library, but several implementations can be found on the net.

Answer (score 1):

Static Maps are a known source of leaks. The reason being that people put stuff in and do not remove them. If every ten minutes you simply clear the cache and then reload then you should be fine.

I would bet that you are not clearing it properly. The GC part is working properly, I would not worry that it is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider using [WeakReference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) if you have some way of falling back to the real data if part of your cache is GC-ed but then subsequently required.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you check the heap contents using a heap dump and a heap analyzer (such as [JVisualVM](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html)). This will help you find leakage suspects. The fact that the old generation is collected less frequently does not mean that more memory is leaking; remember that while it may seem full, only a portion of it represents live objects, and the other portion is clearned by the next major GC. Like others said, the problem may be because of incomplete cleaning of the static collections.

The permanent generation never receives promoted objects. It is an out-of-heap area reserved for other purposes, such as reflective information of loaded classes, and interned strings.